# Programming an ATtiny828 with an Arduino

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, attiny, programmer

I want to upload code using an Arduino to an ATtiny828, is this possible?

I saw on YouTube you can upload code to an ATtiny85.

Thank you in advance. I want to use this for a PCB design that implements a sequential LED light.

Comment: yes. Youtube is arguably not a great source to learn how to work with hardware when you can have the documentation of the folks building the hardware (in fact, a lot of technical content on youtube is outright *bad*, confusing and often wrong). In this case, you'd simply want to read the Attiny828 data sheet about In-system programming and implement that on your arduino. I'm a bit confused what this has to do with [tag:led] or [tag:sequentioal-logic], and I'd ask you to be more selective with the tags you use.

Comment: Thank you and sorry about my mistake. Can you please help me with a diagram, what pins must be connected or some instructions? Is first time for me when i use a ATtiny. I searched on internet but anyting fit my project. Again, sorry for mistake and have a good day!

Comment: sorry, that's a bit too broad; it's a custom design for you, and we're not a free design house.

Comment: Don't search randomly on the internet - instead find the manufacturer's website, then search that site for documents/data sheets on the ATtiny828.  There may be an ATtiny family manual as well as ATtiny828-specific documents that will provide the information you require.

Comment: I don't wanna a free design, just some information. But nevermind, have a good day and thank you for your time for answering me.

Comment: YouTube actually contains plenty of excellent resources for technical guidance on projects. Just remember that nothing is fact except what you've checked and understood for yourself from official documentation. Like anything, YouTube must be interpreted suspiciously - can't follow it blindly, unquestioningly, without thinking. That's true of every technical resource. But YouTube is a fantastic asset for bringing examples and explanations to life - what a terrific addition to the learning process. May clarify the manufacturer's technical datasheets and application notes, making them more real.

Answer (score 2):

ATtiny828 can use casual SPI programming interface. So yes, you can flash sketch named [ArduinoISP](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/ArduinoISP) to your Arduino board and later use avrdude software (or some sort of GUI for it, there are many) to program ATtiny828 target with it.

You can even use [this Arduino core](https://github.com/SpenceKonde/ATTinyCore), which supports ATtiny828, to program your ATtiny828 target from Arduino IDE. You need to install that core in your Arduino IDE, and flash a bootloader via ArduinoISP. Then you can write Arduino sketches for ATtiny828 and program it via UART bootloader (you will need a some sort of USB-UART converter for it). But this is optional.

Comment: Thank you sir! I will do a research. Just to my knowledge: i create a arduino sketch, and "upload" it on my 828 with avrdude?

Comment: Open up Arduino IDE, find an ArduinoISP in the default examples - this is a firmware for your Arduino, to turn it into AVR ISP programmer. Once you program this sketch to your Arduino you can use it to flash your attiny part. Next you either use it as a casual AVR part from Microchip (ex. Atmel) Studio for example. Or use the core I've mentioned to turn it into Arduino IDE  supported part.